How to push a small text into a PDF, simpler than using HPDF?
I need to produce a PDF with a simple text without going through slow latex processing. I have tried a version with HPDF, which seems complicated to use. I got a minimal example working and found it missing

it works on formated lines and thus requires another process to split the text into lines and
it seems to work with some UTF8 charactesrs (for example äöú) but not others (for example  €).

Is there another Haskell package simpler to use or is there a wrapper around HPDF which would transfer a   character (UTF8) text to a PDF?
My example (perhaps useful as a simple example of HPDF usage):
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}


module Main where

import           Graphics.PDF

main :: IO()
main = do
    let rect = PDFRect 0 0 600 400
    Right timesRoman <- mkStdFont Times_Roman 
    runPdf "demoS1.pdf" (standardDocInfo { author="someone"
                                        , compressed = False}) rect $ do
            page1 <- addPage Nothing
            drawWithPage page1 $ do
                drawText $ text (PDFFont timesRoman 40) 10 10 
                    "my test text with äüö but not with €"


sadly, I saw this comment and hoped that some others might know more. Surprising is that some UTF char work, e.g. äöü, but not €, and likely many others, including Cyrillic. Thank you for confirming that this is still open. Unfortunately, I have no experience with how fonts are constructed and used, so I cannot help.

thank you very much for the information - which is now documented and usually findable in stackoverflow; good! I found the design not convincing and documentation lacking. I had difficulties to get my small example working. Probably a fresh start with a new design would be worthwhile.

import Graphics.PDF comes from hackage which usually is found automatically. did you install haskell with ghcup? (highly recommended to avoid installation issues). you can clone the package from https://github.com/hsyl20/HPDF.git but it will ask for other imports then... - I hope you did not delete what you considered non-answers: such pieces may be very valueable for others - they were for me to guess what to do next. thank you!
